# JavaScript - Arrays - Deleting elements from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've looked up arrays and how they work, looked at a lot of other stackoverflow questions on this same topic but the answer still doesn't remain clear. How can I remove a specified element from an array?

I've tried:

```
array.splice(5);
array.splice(i, 5);
delete array[5]; //doesn't actually delete - I know
```

1 of 2 things happen every time. 1. The whole array is deleted with either of the first 2 methods mentioned above. or 2. Everything before/after the element specified is removed.

For example, I had an array that contained a Clash Royale deck:

```
var deck = ["Barbarians", "Goblin_Barrel", "Inferno_Tower", "Fireball", "Zap", "Hog_Rider", "Spear_Goblins", "Minion_Horde"];
```

Then if I wanted to remove, lets say, Fireball, then I did:

```
deck.splice("Fireball");
```

And the array now looked like this:

```
deck = [];
```

So, to restate my question. How do I remove a specified, and only the specified, element from an array?

Comment: Please read [the documentation...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: Also note that we have no idea what `i` is or where you run this code. Always provide [mcve]

Comment: idk what i is. on the forums I read i was never defined so I still dont know how it works

Comment: You can check the array position of the string you're searching for using `indexOf()` and store the result to a variable.  If it's greater than -1 then it belongs to the array.  With that index you can properly use `splice`, passing your variable as the first argument and 1 (the number of items you want to delete, starting at the index) as your second argument.

Comment: *"on the forums I read i was never defined"* - Don't read forums to find out how JS methods work, read *documentation* and then come back to post a question if you still don't understand. MDN has a pretty good JavaScript reference that explains what all of the build-in methods are for, what arguments they expect, etc. If you're ever wondering how *any* JS method works, google "methodname mdn" (e.g., "splice mdn") and usually the first search result will take you to some appropriate doco. (There are other JS references around, but MDN is generally considered the best one.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the usage for `splice` in a [JavaScript reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp). You need to pass in the *index* of the thing to delete, then how many things to delete.

Comment: somewhat shocked that a msft program manager uses **[w3fools](http://www.w3fools.com/)** as docs reference

Comment: what do I do if I don't know where the element I want to delete in the array is?

Comment: It's the first hit on Bing when searching for the method. It appears to be factually correct.

Comment: *"It's the first hit on Bing"* - Well there's your problem. ;) Seriously though, w3schools is much more accurate than it used to be, but it's still somewhat unreliable. Both MDN and MSDN are better. But my main objection to w3schools is that it's still charging people money for certifications with no real-world value.

Comment: @nnnnnn do you at least get a w3fools T-shirt too?

Comment: @charlietfl - Act now and you get a t-shirt *and* a set of steak knives.

Answer (score 0):

First find the index of element then remove it using splice.

Find Index of element

```
var index = deck.indexOf("Fireball");
```

Now remove element using splice.

```
if (index > -1) {
   deck.splice(index,1);
 }
```

if duplicate values exists then

```
for(ind = 0 ; ind <deck.length; ind++){
    if(deck[ind]=="Fireball"){
       deck.splice(ind--,1); 
     }
}
```

Comment: Yep, just be careful to check whether `index` is -1 (i.e. it doesn't exist in the array).  Otherwise you'll be splicing out a value from the end of the array.

Comment: Also, this technique removes the *first* instance of "Fireball", not all instances.

Comment: you also helped a lot too, Thanks!